# sap.ui.commons.Panel Collapse / Expanded event

Tags: sapui5

is it possible to add an event to SAPUI5 `sap.ui.commons.Panel's` minimize and maximize? What i need is to add a different style when the Panel's collapse- or expand-Button is clicked.

If the user clicks on the minus-Symbol i have to add a styleclass like `pnl.addStyleClass("XYZ");` when the user clicks on "maximize" a different styleclass should be added to the panel `pnl.addStyleClass("ZYFDEFD");`

if i overwrite the `.setCollapse-` or `.setExpanded-function` the panel doesn't collapse or expand anymore, so something else has to be found.

Comment: The lib `sap.ui.commons` is deprecated. Use `sap.m.Panel` instead which supports [collapse / expand event](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Panel#events/expand) out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possible options...

1) You could make use the standard style class (sapUiPanelColl) which is added to the control depending on the expanded state - see example below...

```js
var oPanel = new sap.ui.commons.Panel({});
oPanel.addStyleClass("myPanel");
oPanel.placeAt("content");
```

```css
.myPanel { background-color: green; }
.myPanel.sapUiPanelColl { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>sap.ui.commons.Panel style class example</title>
</head>
<body id="content">
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

2) Alternatively, if it's not essential to use the Panel from the commons library you could switch to [sap.m.Panel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Panel.html) (as the [sap.ui.commons.Panel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.Panel.html) is depreciated since version 1.38) and then make use of the [expand event](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Panel.html#event:expand)